# Sparkline composite charts - setting width of second line

Tags: jquery, html, sparklines

I am using sparkline (http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-about) composite charts. I have the following chart and I have set both lines to a width of 2. However, I can only see 1 line with that width. What am I doing wrong?
:

```
                     <div class="sparkline" 
                        data-type="line" 
                        data-resize="true" 
                        data-height="80" 
                        data-width="100%" 
                        data-line-width="2"
                        data-bar-width="5" 
                        data-line-color="#e74c3c" 
                        data-fill-color="#ffada4" 
                        data-highlight-line-color="#e1e5e9" 
                        data-spot-radius="5" 
                        data-data="[120,250,200,325,400,380,250,320,345,250,250,250,200,325,300,365,250,210,200,180,150,160,250,250,250,200,300,310,330,250,320,205]" 
                        data-composite-data="[160,230,250,300,320,330,280,260,250,280,250,260,250,255,330,345,300,210,200,200,170,180,250,250,200,200,280,270,310,250,280,175]" 
                        data-composite-line-width="20"  
                        data-composite-bar-width="2" 
                        data-composite-line-color="#a3e2fe" 
                        data-composite-fill-color="#e3f6ff">
                      </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you also include in your question the javascript you used to instantiate your sparkline graph?

Comment: I've tested with :
     $(function() {
      $('.sparkline').sparkline('html', { enableTagOptions: true, tagOptionsPrefix : 'data-', tagValuesAttribute: 'data-data' });
     });